# How to check the high voltage of a electrostatic device?

Tags: ac, high-voltage, voltage-measurement

I want to build a device with two metal plates which needs to have 3000 VDC between them.
The way that I am thinking is to use a ferrite transformer from a 9 VDC transformer with a transistor that switches a low DC voltage on the original secondary side to get 220 VAC on the original primary side. Like described [here](https://electronics-project-hub.com/make-a-1-5v-to-220v-inverter-circuit/). But that is not the issue here.

By using a series of voltage doublers (in effect a voltage multiplicator) this voltage needs to be upped to 3000 VDC, like described [here](https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/dc-voltage-converter-circuits). Again, the voltage multiplicator is not the issue, but a way to check that high voltage is.

I would like to know of a way to check the output voltage of that circuit without costly and specialized apparatus.

Comment: For some thoughts see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BQM_xw2Rfo).

Comment: Electrostatic VM?

Comment: How about a bog-standard voltage divider?

Answer (score 6):

The best way to measure the resulting DC voltage at the multiplier output is to get a HV probe for your multimeter, but good ones are relatively expensive, I think several hundred $ for a [Fluke one](https://www.myflukestore.ca/pdfs/cache/www.myflukestore.ca/80k-15/manual/80k-15-manual.pdf).

With care you could use a divider with a [100MΩ 1% HV resistor](https://www.murata.com/%7E/media/webrenewal/products/resistor/highvoltage/mhr0624sa_series_data_sheet.ashx?la=en-us), a 10kΩ 1% and a DMM with 10MΩ input resistance to measure the voltage to within a few % for a couple dollars.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0oXri.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A couple caveats:

- This will draw about 10x the current of the Fluke 80K-40 because the
  Fluke uses a 999MΩ resistor, so more loading of your source, which
  will reduce the measured voltage. Of course you could try to source a similar resistor or use 10x 100MΩ resistors but that's more complex. You also would have to know and adjust for DMM input resistance for the best accuracy.
- Don't be disappointed if your multipliers run out of steam at high
  multiplication ratios even without much loading. There's a practical
  maximum of around 10:1 if memory serves.

Comment: I indeed made the mistake by writing 3000 VAC, I corrected this to 3000 VDC.

Comment: Deleted reference to AC.